# Find a regular graph in which $\kappa(G) \neq \lambda(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

The vertex-connectivity, $\kappa(G)$, is the minimum number of nodes whose deletion from a graph G disconnects it.

The edge-connectivity of G, $\lambda(G)$, is the minimum cardinal of the cuts in G.

Now can you find a regular graph in which $\kappa(G) \neq \lambda(G)$ ?

Note: I know this graph is not 3-regular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following graph is 4-regular with $\kappa =1$ , and $\lambda =2$. Note that for any graph $G$, $\kappa(G)\leq \lambda(G)$.

[image]

Comment: thank you, it's correct :) but i think you made a mistake : for any graph $\kappa(G) \le \lambda(G)$

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Thanks, I edit the answer.